# Django: display queryset in its corresponding ID (multiple ID)

Tags: django

My model is like this:

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    hospital_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hospital_ategory = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=ETABLISSEMENTS)
    imagePopup = models.ImageField(upload_to='default/', default='default/musta.jpg')
    wilaya = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=WILAYA)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    location = PointField(srid=4326)
    @property
    def lat_lng(self):
        return list(getattr(self.location, 'coords', []) [::-1])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hospital_name


class Hospitalservice(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='services')
    name_service = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    responsable_service = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    service_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    service_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} à l'hopital {}".format(self.name_service, self.post.hospital_name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-service_date', )


class Bedservice(models.Model):
    post_bed = models.ForeignKey(Hospitalservice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bed')
    bed_number_total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    bed_number_used = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_bed.name_service
```

`

views.py looks like this:

```
class HospitalTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'health/hospital_map.html'
    queryset = Hospital.objects.all()  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = HospitalForm()
        ...
        ...
        ...

        return context


def detail_imp_map(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Hospital, id=id)
    services = post.services.filter(active=True)

    post_bed = get_object_or_404(Hospitalservice, pk=id)
    bed_service = post_bed.bed.filter(active=True)
        
    columns = ['bed_number_total']
    num = reduce(add, (F(column) for column in columns ))
    Total_sum= Bedservice.objects.aggregate(total=Sum(num))
    if request.method == "POST":
        service_form = HospitalServiceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if service_form.is_valid():
            new_point = service_form.save(commit=False)
            new_point.post = post
            new_point.save()
            return redirect('hospital_map')
    else:
        service_form = HospitalServiceForm()
    context={
        'post': post,
        'post_bed': post_bed,
        'Total_sum': Total_sum,
        'services':services,
        'service_form':service_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'health/detail_imp_from_map.html', context)


def detail_hosp_map(request, id):
    result = Bedservice.objects.all().annotate(difference=F('bed_number_total') - 
             F('bed_number_used'))

    post_bed = get_object_or_404(Hospitalservice, id=id)
    bed_service = post_bed.bed.filter(active=True)

    post_medecin = get_object_or_404(Hospitalservice, id=id)
    medecin_service = post_medecin.medecin.filter(active=True)

    if request.method == "POST":
        service_bed_form = BedserviceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        medecin_service_form = MedecinForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if service_bed_form.is_valid():
            new_point_service_bed = service_bed_form.save(commit=False)
            new_point_service_bed.post_bed = post_bed
            new_point_service_bed.save()
            return redirect('hospital_map')
        if medecin_service_form.is_valid():
            new_point_service_medecin = medecin_service_form.save(commit=False)
            new_point_service_medecin.post_medecin = post_medecin
            new_point_service_medecin.save()
            return redirect('hospital_map')
    else:
        service_bed_form = BedserviceForm()
        medecin_service_form = MedecinForm()
    context={
        'result':result,
        'bed_service': bed_service,
        'medecin_service': medecin_service,
        'post_bed': post_bed,
        'post_medecin': post_medecin,
        'service_bed_form': service_bed_form,
        'medecin_service_form': medecin_service_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'health/detail_service.html', context)
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'hospital_map/', HospitalTemplateView.as_view(), name='hospital_map'),
    path(r'hospital_map/<int:id>/', detail_imp_map, name='detail'),
    path(r'detail_service/<int:id>/', detail_hosp_map, name='detail_service'),
    url('^health/', include('health.urls', namespace='health')),

    path('add_impact/', addImpactOnMap, name='add_impact'),
    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

By using

```
columns = ['bed_number_total']
num = reduce (add, (F (column) for column in columns))
Total_sum = Bedservice.objects.aggregate (total = Sum (num))
```

I get `bed_number_total` in all departments of all hospitals. So what I want here. How to display the sum of `bed_number_total` and the sum of `bed_number_used` for all departments in each hospital (each hospital has its own id). So if anyone can provide any advice on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change your models (you could include the counts in the model).

Without getting into complicated aggregates. In the case you want to count it per hospital you can either loop throught the objects and count it:

```
hospitals_res = Hospital.objects.all()
result = []
for hospital_find in hospitals_res:
    hospitalservices = Hospitalservice.objects.filter(post = hospital_find)

    for service in hospitalservices:
        bed_services = Bedservice.objects.filter(post_bed = service)
        
        used = 0
        total = 0
        for bed_serv in bed_services:
            used = used + bed_serv.bed_number_used
            total = total + bed_serv.bed_number_total
            
        result.append({'hospital_id': hospital_find.id, 'used_beds':used, 'total_beds':total})
```

Or just use a raw query: (always be careful to escape any parameters passed)

```
query = """
                SELECT
            hospital.id as id,
            SUM(bedservice.bed_number_total) as total,
            SUM(bedservice.bed_number_used) as used
        FROM
            backend_admin_hospital AS hospital
        LEFT JOIN backend_admin_hospitalservice AS hospitalservice ON post_id = hospital.id 
        LEFT JOIN backend_admin_bedservice AS bedservice ON post_bed_id =  hospitalservice.id
        
        GROUP BY hospital.id
    """
    result = Hospital.objects.raw(query)
```

Comment: Thank you @TomTom. That didn't worked. What I want how to sum number of beds in each hospital.For ex if:
hospital_1 (`hospital_name`) has service_ophtalmology (`name_service`) widh 122beds (`bed_number_total`), service_cardiology (`name_service`) widh 231bed (`bed_number_total`) etc.
hospital_2 has service_neurology widh 333bed, service_maternity widh 500bed etc.
hospital_3 etc.
How to sum (or count) the totalnumber of beds in hospital_1, hospital_2, hospital_x etc.
and call it in template. each hospital has its ID (`/hospital_map/1/ for hospital_1`, `/hospital_map/x/ for hospital_x` etc.

Comment: So just to clarify you want the sum number of beds per hospitalservice then, no? So then Hospital1 -> Service 1 with 100 beds, Service 2 with 50 beds. Or do you mean sum number of beds in each hospital as Hospital 1 with 150 beds?

Comment: Yes I want the second suggestion. I want to sum number of beds in each hospital as Hospital 1 with 150 beds.

Comment: Thank you very much @TomTom. To focus `used_beds` and `total_beds` in each `Hospitalservice` for each `Hospital ` that you have definde, I juste put `hospital_id` from `result.append({'hospital_id': hospital_find.id, 'used_beds':used, 'total_beds':total})`  instead `r.hospital_id`,  which I put at the beginning. I am very happy with your help.

Comment: @MohamedHassani good to hear, if you are happy with the answer you can mark it as resolved with a tick box next to the answer